# Joomla: how to display sub-menu items

Tags: joomla, menu

I created a website using Joomla! 3.4.1. It has some categories and the main menu looks like this:

- Home

  - Main Category

    - Category 1

      - Category 1.1

        - Category 1.1.1
        - Category 1.1.2
        - Category 1.1.3
      - Category 1.2
      - Category 1.3
    - Category 2

      - Category 2.1
      - Category 2.2

I decided (I'm not sure if it was the best decision) to create the complete website structure in the main menu.

Now, in the "Category 1" page, I would like to have a menu showing some selected sub-menu items, for example:

Category 1 Menu:

- Category 1.1
- Category 1.3

In order to achieve this, I decided to create a new menu called "Category 1 Menu" with menu item aliases (to avoid creating new URLs).

Until now everything was ok, the problem is now I want to display Category 1.1 sub-items, but I just want to display the children of Category 1.1 when Category 1.1 is selected. Something like this:

Category 1

- Category 1.1
- Category 1.3

And if I click on "Category 1.1" its items should expand like this:

Category 1

- Category 1.1

  - Category 1.1.1
  - Category 1.1.2
  - Category 1.1.3
- Category 1.3

Remember, all these items are menu item aliases.

I know how to do it without usign menu item aliases but in this case, I think that I need to use menu item aliases, otherwise I won't have a complete "tree" structure in the breadcrumbs.

What can I do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

if you don't wanna use aliases you can easily create a module or search for one in JED. Basically code for sub menu is like this:

```
$menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();
$active = $menu->getActive();
$childs = $menu->getItems('parent_id', $active->id);
//now if childs are empty yoy don't have a submenu
if( !empty($childs) )
{
    //show menu using foreach $childs as $child and creating friendly url using JRoute
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Lanah. To be honest, I prefer to use aliases because it's the way is done now and I already have hundreds of menu items (it's a big website). But how can I make it work as expected? Do I need to change the module code? Or is there a way to do it without changing it? Thanks

Comment: So you have a one option, use aliases, my web page use it too, when we reached 100+ links we start to be confused but now its okey.  : )

Comment: Thanks @Lanah. In this case, how can I expand the sub-menu items only when I click on the parent item? I know it works with "normal" menu items. But for some reason when I use menu item aliases, it does not expand the sub-menu items

Comment: Now it's depends on your template and module displaying menu. Check module Params and templates Params.

Comment: Thanks @Lanah! I'm using protostar template and the default Menu module. My settings are Base Item: Current; Start Level: 1; End Level: All; Show Sub-menu Items: No. This menu is composed only by menu item aliases. If I use "regular" menu items it works. I started testing the code and the problem is when I do `$menu->getActive();` it does not retrieve the id of the menu item alias but the original menu item. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance